# Running a Rails application on multiple ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I have a rails application which I am running on the default port 3000 as well as on port 80 using passenger. Are there any downsides of this ?

Comment: If you've got ports, why not use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, other than two instances of Rails server running.  As long as they're on different ports you're fine.

As an alternative to Passenger I recommend taking a look at pow (http://pow.cx) as a way of running multiple instances with domain names with minimal fuss.

Comment: Pow is not suitable for production environments. It's designed for development.

Comment: He's running on a dev box, hence the port 3000 in his question.